# Kotlin: repeat n time while condition is true

Tags: loops, kotlin, conditional-statements, idioms

I need to repeat a piece of code a maximum of n times, but terminate the loop once a condition is false, like in the following:

```
val runs = 100
var ctr = 0
var condition = true

while (ctr++ < runs && condition) {
    //stuff and updates
}
```

Can this logic be stated more idiomatic, maybe with *repeat*?

Comment: I think that’s the cleanest way to do it. `repeat` relies on lambdas, which don’t support `break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest lambdas and [non-locally return to the outer one](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) - I won't say this is pretty but it's an option:

```
run loop@{
    repeat(100) {
        if(!condition) return@loop
        // stuff and updates
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I won't use that but nice to know nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would consider an idiomatic way of doing this, lazily generate a sequence, limit to 100, stop on the first `condition==true` then do something if not null (i.e. `condition==true`)

```kotlin
            generateSequence {
                // do stuff per iteration
                Unit // or whatever value per iteration
            }.take(100).firstOrNull { condition }?.let {
                // on condition
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val runs = 100
var condition = true


for(ctr in (0..runs)){
    if(condition){
        //stuff and updates
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop will still go through each iteration just to check that condition is false. Thats a lot of wasted effort if runs is a large number, and condition turns false quickly.